# im trying to use the seed migrate in the cmd terminal straight from the projects folder and its not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image: screenshot]

somebody whomight know whats causing the error please help me

here is the results after i try run the php artisan migrate

```bash
The command "mysql --user="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_USER}"
--password="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PASSWORD}"
--host="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST}"
--port="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT}"
--database="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_DATABASE}" < "${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PATH}"" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\FoodTigerv3.5

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Add code from seed file to the question please.

Answer (score 0):

The [artisan console](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan) doesn't seem to do MySQL jobs itself. It uses the `mysql` command line tool to work. This require you to have a [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/) installed in your shell environment. You'd also need to add the path to the tool to your [PATH](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) setting.

Comment: add which path bruv??...ive never used mysql shell..just downloaded it

Comment: First you should use File Explorer to search "C:\Program Files" and "C:\Program Files (x86)" for the MySQL client folder. Look for the folder with mysql.exe and that should be it.

Comment: After setting the PATH, you can open Command Prompt and type `mysql --help`. If it shows you help message about the MySQL tool, you 're doing right. If it complains that it cannot find mysql, then your PATH setup is wrong.